# PHPMailer and Mail() both failing? From Address failed

Tags: php, apache, email, phpmailer

```
require_once("libphp-phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.comcast.net";
//$mail->Host = "localhost";

//$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->WordWrap = 60;

//$mail->SetFrom("jharvard@cs50.net");
$mail->SetFrom("testmail@example.com");

$mail->AddAddress("kyzcreig@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = "BUY! Receipt";
$mail->Body = 
    "You just bought {$_POST["symbol"]}: \n\n";

if ($mail->Send() == false) {
    die($mail->ErrInfo);
}
```

I get this error when I run the above code:

[image]

Not sure what it means.  I'm fairly new to PHP too so maybe I'm missing something?

If I try to use the generic mail() function that also fails.  Although it doesn't give any error message.

Comment: shouldn;t this $mail->ErrInfo be $mail->ErrorInfo

Comment: Most ISPs will only send mail from an address they recognise on their own servers. `example.com` is a reserved domain, so the mail server has rejected your email because it doesn't recognise the address.

Comment: correct Satya: I now get this error: SMTP server error: 5.1.0 Authentication required

Comment: Hobo, is there a way around that?  In the LH article they spoof fb.com : http://lifehacker.com/how-spammers-spoof-your-email-address-and-how-to-prote-1579478914  I'm not interested in spoofing, but I'd like to at least get this working.

Comment: @veta test with legit addresses from and to

Comment: hey dagon, I did try this out and it works.  I don't want to be using my gmail account though.  I'm also taking a MOOC right now where the professor spoofs the FromAddress and I'd like to get it working on my end that way.

Comment: I would suggest trying to use a different domain other than example.com for a from address. If you run your website with your own domain name, try setting up an email address with it (if possible) and use that instead. Otherwise, try an email address that is 100% valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had no default SMTP settings so naturally the default mail() wasn't working.  I configured things to use first my gmail account/smtp server and then later (so I could spoof headers) my hostgator smtp server.

This resolved the issue.